# Laravel + Vite Production Issue

Tags: laravel, vite

The website in production is broken.. I'm utilizing Vite to bundle my assets. Below is my code:

**`vite.config.js`**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'public/assets/css/line-awesome.min.css',
                'public/assets/fonts/stylesheet.css',
                'public/assets/css/fontawesome-all.css'
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Http/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

**`app.blade.php`**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    @vite('public/assets/fonts/stylesheet.css')
    @vite('public/assets/css/line-awesome.min.css')
    @vite('public/assets/css/fontawesome-all.css')

    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.12.3/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'app') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

</head>
```

**`.gitignore`**

```js
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.env.production
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
auth.json
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
/.fleet
/.idea
/.vscode
```

**`app.js`**

```js
import './bootstrap';
import 'flowbite';


import { MeiliSearch } from 'meilisearch'

window.MeiliSearch = MeiliSearch

import search from "./components/search";

window.components = {
    search,
};

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();
```

In production, the assets are generated and the asset links are functioning, but the website itself appears broken. I've ensured that the asset paths are correctly configured, but there seems to be an issue that I can't pinpoint. Any guidance or assistance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

i looked online and solutions i found does not seem to work.